# Add object to list of same object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I got this to classes:

```
public class NotifyUser : ContentPage
{
    public NotifyUser()
    {
        Friends = new List<FriendStatus>();
    }
    public string Namn { get; set; }
    public List<FriendStatus> Friends { get; set; }

}

public class FriendStatus
{
    public FriendStatus()
    {
        Name = "";
        Checked = false;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}
```

And I got this method where I try to create a new object and add to the list.

```
public void AddFriend(string namn)
{
    namn = "Bob";
    string user = User.Identity.GetUserName();
    var loggedinuser = RavenSession
        .Load<ContentPage>("NotifyUser/" + user) as NotifyUser;

    var fr = new FriendStatus { Name = namn, Checked = false };

    loggedinuser.Friends.Add(fr);
    RavenSession.SaveChanges();
}

loggedinuser.Friends is a list of `frienstatus`,
```

When I try to add my newly created object to the list I get an `Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`, can someone see what i have missed?

I thought my list was instantiated in the class with this line

```
public NotifyUser()
        {
            Friends = new List<FriendStatus>();
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Creating a new `NotifyUser` object doesn't create a new list in the object.  You have to do that either in the constructor or in your calling code (`loggedinuser.Friends = new List<FriendStatus>();`.

Comment: he does instantiate it in the constructor

Comment: @Tim: It's already in the constructor. Look at the top of the question.

Comment: Are you sure `var loggedinuser = RavenSession.Load<ContentPage>("NotifyUser/" + user) as NotifyUser` doesn't return null?

Comment: Please format your post - the code is all over the place at the moment. You've asked over 100 questions - there's really no excuse for continuing to post sloppily-formatted code.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Oops...I completely missed that line.

Comment: @JonSkeet Except, of course, that he posts so many questions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *strongly* suspect that this line is the problem:

```
var loggedinuser = RavenSession.Load<ContentPage>("NotifyUser/" + user) as NotifyUser;
```

`loggedinuser` will be null if the `Load` method actually returns something other than a `NotifyUser`. This is where it's better to use a cast than `as` - it means that if your type is wrong, you get a *meaningful* exception immediately rather than a `NullReferenceException` later on. (See my blog post on [embracing exceptions](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2013/09/19/casting-vs-quot-as-quot-embracing-exceptions/) for more about this.)

I don't know anything about `RavenSession`, but I wouldn't be surprised if you really wanted:

```
var loggedinuser = RavenSession.Load<NotifyUser>("NotifyUser/" + user);
```

If you *must* use `RavenSession.Load<ContentPage>`, you should change your code to use a cast instead of `as`. That way, if `loggedinuser` is null, that definitely means that `Load` returned null.

Additionally, you should use a debugger to check this sort of thing - that would easily have allowed you to differentiate between `loggedinuser` being null and `loggedinuser.Friends` being null.

Comment: Thabk you Jon, i will look at this in the morning and get back to you